# Android: Custom View in XML-Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to add a ListView and a Custom View in my layout, but I always get this error:

"...Error inflating class com.example..."

Without the Custom View it works and only the ListView is shown.

---

Activity:

```
package com.example.training;

public class PracticeActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.practice_layout);
      initListView();  //private function
   }
   //Other stuff
}
```

Custom View:

```
package com.example.training;

public class LinearChart extends View{

  LinearChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context,attrs);
  }

  LinearChart(Context context){
      super(context);
  }

  LinearChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
      super(context,attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
      Paint paint = new Paint();
      paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
      canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 30, 30, paint); 
  }
}
```

XML-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/practice_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

    <view
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/practice_listview"
        class="com.example.training.LinearChart" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you clean your project to refresh the generated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public constructors on your class. Make sure you override the constructors. It should look like this instead:

```
  public LinearChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context,attrs);
  }

  public LinearChart(Context context){
      super(context);
  }

  public LinearChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
      super(context,attrs, defStyle);
  }
```

Notice the addiction of `public` modifier.

Comment: Can not believe that this is the solution :D Thanks alot

Comment: You can check your logcat for more information. Normaly this will throw `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]` which tells you that the constructor was not found. The default access modifier is private so `LayoutInflater` couldn't find it. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/practice_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>

<com.example.training.LinearChart
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/practice_listview"
     />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show me the exception. but first clean the project and rebuild it by placing my code in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<view` in your xml file, you need the fully qualified name of the class (or use a new xml namespace). So, in this example, your xml might look like:

```
<com.example.training.LinearChart
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

(and therefore remove the class: attribute in your current XML). This should then inflate correctly.

Comment: That's the same thing. You don't "need" to do this way.